# phonegap build 3.3.0 + pushwoosh not working

Tags: push-notification, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, pushwoosh, phonegap-pushplugin

I installed according to this guide: http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/android-additional-platforms/phonegap-build/

And I defined in pushwoosh the Certificate is needed. 
IOS system I get an error

`your provisioning profile does not have aps entry. Please make your profile push compatible`

And Android app costs but I send notifications are not coming.

Where could be the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recreate your mobileprovisioning profile for the app in Apple Developer Portal.
Your current mobileprovisioning profile does not allow push notifications.
After recreating the profile, open it in any text editor and double check that it has "aps-environment" line.

Comment: Okay what about android?